# Calling methods from an array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, call

Is there a way in Java to call methods from an array? I want to design a primitive board game and I would like to use an array of methods to represent the game spaces.

Comment: you call methods on an array, you pass the board cell to the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the basic idea (Command pattern)

```
static Runnable[] methods = new Runnable[10];

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    methods[0] = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("method-0");
        }
    };
    methods[1] = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("method-1");
        }
    };
    ...
    methods[1].run();
}
```

output

```
method-1
```

or with reflection

```
static Method[] methods = new Method[10];

public static void method1() {
    System.out.println("method-1");
}

public static void method2() {
    System.out.println("method-2");
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    methods[0] = Test1.class.getDeclaredMethod("method1");
    methods[1] = Test1.class.getDeclaredMethod("method2");
    methods[1].invoke(null);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

perhaps you need to use some sort of Command pattern, like

```
class Board {
   Cell[][] cells = new Cell[5][5];

   void addCell(int i, int j, Cell cell) {
     cells[i,j] = cell;
   }

   void executeCell(int i, int j) {
     cells[i,j].execute(this);
   }
}

interface Cell {
   void execute(Board board);
}

class CellImpl implements Cell {
  void execute(Board board) {
    // do your stuff here
  }
}
```

you may add as much implementations as you wish, as soon as they implement Cell interface - board can execute them.